# Android BLE Scanning and Connection taking too long compared to direct connection through mac

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have a simple android app which needs to connect to our hardware through BLE.

In iOS both the cases have almost same time.

Case 1:

- Scan for the service Id.
- Get the results.
- Connect
- Discover services

Case 2:

- Connect directly through Mac
- Discover Services

Library Used: `Android-Scanner-Compat-Library`

Code:

Scanning:

```
scanner = BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner();
final ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .setUseHardwareBatchingIfSupported(false).build();
final List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
Log.i(TAG, "Scanning.....");
scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback);
mHandler.postDelayed(() -> {
        stopScan();
}, SCAN_DURATION);
```

Stop scanning:

```
scanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
```

Comment: I don't know if it is your question. However you can't compare the connection/scanning time between android and iOS. Sure on the hardware side its pretty the same, but the OS is way different and how it's handled inside the OS. And the hardware is also maybe not the same, it might be the same BLE Chip, but same CPU, etc. is unlikly So you can't compare the connection time.

Comment: I agree that we cannot compare the performance of both the systems. My question is how do I reduce the time in Case 1 to match with Case 2.

Comment: You can save the mac adress to connect directly. But you always have to connect initially.Or if you know the device name you can also connect directly to the name, but keep in mind that not every time the name is discoverd. Its also possible to use the syntax of a mac adress to quick connect and filter for spesific parts

Comment: The problem with connecting directly with mac address is, there will be multiple devices associated with the user account, so the app needs to scan to see with device is in range. So I was wondering how to reduce the time between scanning and discovering the services.

Comment: You can save time, if you bond the ble device to your smartphone.